# Mock.assert_has_calls() not working as expected

Tags: python, django, python-unittest.mock

I have this unit test where I want to ensure my Django custom management job is writing specific messages to its log.

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

...

    @override_settings(HR_SYNC_DATA_DIR=f"{settings.BASE_DIR}/core/management/tests/HR_SYNC_DATA_DIR")
    @patch('core.management.commands.process_hr_changes.log')
    @patch('core.management.commands.process_hr_changes.requests.get')
    def test_sync_users2(self, mock_get, mock_log):
        #
        # Load our Mock data
        #
        test_data_dir = f"{settings.BASE_DIR}/core/management/tests/TEST_DATA_DIR"
        get_mocks = []
        for filename in glob.glob(path.join(test_data_dir, 'test-data-hrdata_underrun_page_*.json')):
            with open(filename, "r") as infile:
                mock_response = Mock(ok=True)
                mock_response.json.return_value = json.load(infile)
                mock_response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
                get_mocks.append(mock_response)
        mock_get.side_effect = get_mocks
        with self.assertRaises(CommandError) as context:
            call_command('process_hr_changes')
        print(context.exception)
        self.assertEqual('percent change is -0.125 and delta_pct is 0.1. Lifecycle is dev.', context.exception.args[0])
        mock = Mock(return_value=None)
        info_calls = [
            mock.call('rehires = 0 new hires = 0 terminations = 5.'),
            mock.call('process_hr_changes args are: delta_pct 0.1 how_many_hours_back 24 dry_run False debug is False verbose is False'),
            mock.call('test: startup'),
            mock.call('Removing directory /apps/core/management/tests/HR_SYNC_DATA_DIR.'),
            mock.call('Creating directory /apps/core/management/tests/HR_SYNC_DATA_DIR.'),
            mock.call('percent change is -0.125 and delta_pct is 0.1.'),
        ]
        for mock_call in mock_log.info.mock_calls:
            print(mock_call)
        mock_log.info.assert_has_calls(info_calls, any_order=True)
```

When I run this test it fails on the `mock_log.info.assert_has_calls(info_calls, any_order=True)` statement with this message:

```
AssertionError: (<MagicMock name='log.call()' id='140711932625744'>, <MagicMock name='log.call()' id='140711932625744'>, <MagicMock name='log.call()' id='140711932625744'>, <MagicMock name='log.call()' id='140711932625744'>, <MagicMock name='log.call()' id='140711932625744'>, <MagicMock name='log.call()' id='140711932625744'>) not all found in call list
```

I also see this output from my print statement:

```
call('process_hr_changes args are: delta_pct 0.1 how_many_hours_back 24 dry_run False debug is False verbose is False')
call('test: startup')
call('Removing directory /apps/core/management/tests/HR_SYNC_DATA_DIR.')
call('Creating directory /apps/core/management/tests/HR_SYNC_DATA_DIR.')
call('rehires = 0 new hires = 0 terminations = 5.')
call('percent change is -0.125 and delta_pct is 0.1.')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I had to change my code to this:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch, call  # need to import call.

...

        info_calls = [
            call('rehires = 0 new hires = 0 terminations = 5.'),
            call('process_hr_changes args are: delta_pct 0.1 how_many_hours_back 24 dry_run False debug is False verbose is False'),
            call('test: startup'),
            call('Removing directory /apps/core/management/tests/HR_SYNC_DATA_DIR.'),
            call('Creating directory /apps/core/management/tests/HR_SYNC_DATA_DIR.'),
            call('percent change is -0.125 and delta_pct is 0.1.'),

        ]
        mock_log.info.assert_has_calls(info_calls, any_order=True)
```

Comment: I think you need to pass the top-level [`call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#call) object to `assert_has_calls`, not the result of `Mock.call`.

Comment: Yes after taking a closer look at the docs it appears you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the result of `Mock.call` to `assert_has_calls`. But, `assert_has_calls` expects a top-level [`call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#call) object.

---

Note, after reading the docs I concur this is not overly clear. Here's the docs for [`assert_has_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls):

> assert the mock has been called with the specified calls. The mock_calls list is checked for the calls.
>
> If any_order is false then the calls must be sequential. There can be extra calls before or after the specified calls.
>
> If any_order is true then the calls can be in any order, but they must all appear in mock_calls.
>
> ```py
> mock = Mock(return_value=None)
> mock(1)
> mock(2)
> mock(3)
> mock(4)
> calls = [call(2), call(3)]
> mock.assert_has_calls(calls)
> calls = [call(4), call(2), call(3)]
> mock.assert_has_calls(calls, any_order=True)
> ```

It's not clear where the `call` object comes from in that example. I can see the confusion.

It's only when you see the [`call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#call) documentation that it gets a bit clearer (emphasis mine):

> call() is a helper object for making simpler assertions, for comparing with call_args, call_args_list, mock_calls and method_calls. **call() can also be used with assert_has_calls()**.